# Neptune | Gremlin Python | Parallel queries using websockets

Tags: websocket, python-multiprocessing, amazon-neptune, gremlinpython

What is the best way to execute parallel queries from gremlin python jupyter notebook to a Neptune cluster? I am trying to solve this using the Multiprocess package in Python. However my three db.r5.4xlarge readers max out very soon at 100% CPU as shown in the graph below. Graph 1 is CPU utilisation and graph 2 is gremlin errors. Below is my code. Is there a way this can be tackled better using websockets? If yes can you please help me with that since I am very new to gremlin or neptune.

```
params = [tuple(x) for x in new_registrations_list[['id','createddate']].values]
pool = Pool(42)
df=pool.starmap(process_vertex,params)
pool.close()


def process_vertex(vertex_id, reg_date):    
    g=neptune.graphTraversal(neptune_endpoint='neptune-endpoint', neptune_port=xxx1x)
    vertices=g.V(str(vertex_id)).repeat(__.both().dedup()).emit().project('id').by(T.id).toList()
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: CPU utilization depends on the query performance. And even if it is parallel processing, neptune parallel processing depends on the number of cores and vCpu. Every query execution blocks the one core. So if the query response time is high, subsequent queries will be accumulated in the input queue of neptune.

Comment: You can monitor the pending requests in cloudwatch metrics. MainRequestQueuePendingRequests for your neptune cluster or instance.